# Commercial (Super Bowl?) where guy looks mean but is nice

Tags: story-identification

Since the Super Bowl is coming up, I thought I'd ask this ad identification question, and hope this is the right place.

**Background:**

I remember watching a commercial a long time ago (maybe 20 years?) that I really liked.  I thought it was a Super Bowl ad, but I spent a while last year looking through the list of ads for the years I thought it might be and could not find it.  When I tell other people about it they are usually intrigued and would like to watch it, but no one has thought definitely that they've seen it...maybe it was a dream?

**Here's what I remember:**

There's a guy walking through different scenes, I think starting on a city sidewalk and possibly moving inside.

While he's walking he does what appears to be mean things.  He trips a little kid who starts crying, he pushes someone over from behind who falls over and angrily glares at the guy, etc.  The whole time the guy has a smirk on his face.

However, each time it turns out that the person he was "mean" to is saved from catastrophe.  The kid he trips was chasing a ball and the ball gets run over by a passing car, a piano crashes right where the person he pushed from behind would have been standing, and this goes on through the end of the commercial.

**Supplication:**

I've searched google, youtube, super bowl commercial lists, friends and strangers memories, etc. but have had no luck.  Thus, I'm hoping someone here might know of this and will be able to point me in the right direction (or confirm my insanity).  Thanks much for your help!

Comment: Can you point out the science fiction or fantasy aspect of this? It sounds like it could have been established he was precognitive, but your description doesn't mention that.

Comment: I don't think it's Super Bowl specific? I've a vague memory of a similar ad, which would have just been on regular TV in the UK. (Also, probably unrelated, but sounded like it might have been a spoof of the music video for Bitter Sweet Symphony - turns out that song [was used](http://www.mtv.com/news/2752/the-verve-go-commercial-with-bitter-sweet-symphony/) in a 1998 Nike ad that premiered during and NFC game)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Yes, while the main character in the ad did have an uncanny knack to seem to be able to see and change the future (possibly even to the point of being precognitive as you say), the case for this being Sci-Fi is admittedly a bit lacking.  I originally thought to post this on "Movies & TV", but over there they have all identification questions as "Off Topic".

Comment: @Mohirl Thanks for the response!  I'm in the US, so it's possible it was both on UK and US networks.  I took a look at the [Bitter Sweet Symphony music video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1lyu1KKwC74) and that is very close, though lacking the good results.  I think you are on to something with the '98 Nike ad, as the I'm a fan of the MN Vikings and that was their best season, and I definitely watched the post-season games that year!

Comment: @Mohirl Hmm, I found it but looks like it wasn't [that one](http://www.thevervelive.com/2008/05/infamous-nike-commercial.html), unfortunately.  Still on the lookout, but thanks again for the response!

Comment: Slapstick comedy isn't (big f) Fantasy.

Comment: FYI:  I know this is closed now, but I finally found it!  Thanks to those that helped!  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gJcNsZOOGmY

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have found the one I was thinking of. It was [an ad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_SsccRkLLzU) for The Guardian (newspaper) from 1986. It's probably not yours but posting just in case.

Seems far too early for my memory of it, but I may have seen it later in a program about advertising. Apparently it won awards so presumably would have been well  known, so if it's not your one perhaps it influenced yours? Might be  a starting point.

Weirdly, I found it by googling "commercial piano falling", despite it not involving a piano.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Not the exact one I was thinking of (was 3 when that aired), but similar concept.